# How to add and implement configure flags in Autotools?

Tags: configuration, build-process, autotools

A portion of our research group's program has auxiliary functionality provided by [ctemplate](http://code.google.com/p/google-ctemplate/) library. On our dated cluster, we can not build the software due to compilation , so I would like to separate this functionality and control whether it is included or not via a `configure` flag, such as `--disable-ctemplate`.

The software, written in C++, uses the Autotools build system—neither of which I have much experience with. My understanding is that to accomplish this task, I need to do the following:

1. Add a new flag to the configure script by creating a new `AC_ARG_ENABLE` entry in `configure.ac`.
2. Add some `#ifdef` (or possibly `#ifndef`) statements around the code that uses the `ctemplate` library, and around any code that calls that code.

I think the first step would look something like this:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(ctemplate,
[  --disable-ctemplate    Disable HTML output],
[case "${enableval}" in
  yes) ctemplate=false ;;
  no)  ctemplate=true ;;
  *) AC_MSG_ERROR(bad value ${enableval} for --disable-ctemplate) ;;
esac],[ctemplate=true])
AM_CONDITIONAL(NOCTEMPLATE, test x$ctemplate = xfalse)
```

though I don't know if the logic is correct, since I've adapted this example from examples that used `--enable-FLAG` instead of `--disable-FLAG`.

For the second step, I'll wrap sections in preprocessor flags such as

```
#ifndef NOCTEMPLATE
void Class::MethodUsingCtemplate(...)
{
    ...
}
#endif
```

Would this correctly "wire up" everything if I did `configure --disable-ctemplate`?

Also, will this ensure that the program does not go into the `ctemplate` library for compilation? If not, then all of this is for nothing; it's imperative that I can prevent compilation of the `ctemplate` library and dependent components.

I'll re-iterate that I'm unfamiliar with both C++ and Autotools; I have taken a very naive first approach at solving this problem. If you have experience in this area, I would really appreciate your corrections and any explanations you could offer.

Comment: *＋1*. This should be in the Autotools manual instead of requiring people to piece it together, look it up on a mailing list or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution that I put together after reading through documentation, tutorials, help threads, mailing lists, etc., and just plain trying things until they worked I could explain why they worked.

In `configure.ac`, I placed the following lines of code

```
# This adds the option of compiling without using the ctemplate library,
# which has proved troublesome for compilation on some platforms
AC_ARG_ENABLE(ctemplate,
  [ --disable-ctemplate   Disable compilation with ctemplate and HTML output],
  [case "${enableval}" in
     yes | no ) WITH_CTEMPLATE="${enableval}" ;;
     *) AC_MSG_ERROR(bad value ${enableval} for --disable-ctemplate) ;;
   esac],
  [WITH_CTEMPLATE="yes"]
)

dnl Make sure we register this option with Automake, so we know whether to
dnl descend into ctemplate for more configuration or not
AM_CONDITIONAL([WITH_CTEMPLATE], [test "x$WITH_CTEMPLATE" = "xyes"])

# Define CTEMPLATE in config.h if we're going to compile against it
if test "x$WITH_CTEMPLATE" = "xyes"; then
    AC_DEFINE([CTEMPLATE], [], ["build using ctemplate library"])
    AC_MSG_NOTICE([ctemplate will be used, HTML output enabled])
else
    AC_MSG_NOTICE([ctemplate will not be used, HTML output disabled])
fi
```

In the next step, I changed the `Makefile.am` at the top level to the following:

```
if WITH_CTEMPLATE
  MAYBE_CTEMPLATE = ctemplate
endif

SUBDIRS = boost libgsl $(MAYBE_CTEMPLATE) libutil ...
```

In lower level `Makefile.am`s, I added

```
if WITH_CTEMPLATE
    # some change to the configuration
else
    # some other change to the configuration
endif
```

Finally, I had to make sure that one of the key C++ header files (included by other parts of the code) had the following:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#    include "config.h"
#endif
```

`config.h` contains any new definitions one creates with `AC_DEFINE`, so this file must be included in parts that check whether a macro definition created by this route is defined (or undefined).

This took a lot of time and pushing through frustration on my part; I can only hope documenting this explanation here saves someone else from the same fate.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the build from attempting to compile in the ctemplate subdirectory, you'll want to do something like:

```
if CTEMPLATE
SUBDIRS += ctemplate
endif
```

in Makefile.am